# On page refresh , set default value of drop down on angunlar 9

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular9, angular10

Here is my `HTML` file I am using `p-dropdown`:

```
<p-dropdown id="userType" 
  name="userType" 
  inputId="userType" 
  formControlName="userType" 
  [required]="true"
  [tabindex]="1" 
  optionLabel="title" 
  dataKey="id" 
  [options]="userTypeList"
  placeholder="{{'Select user Type'|translate}}" 
  dropdownIcon="pi pi-caret-down"
  (onChange)="onUserTypeChange($event)">
</p-dropdown>
```

and here in my `ts` file, I'm populating dropdown through an `array`:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.getUserTypeList();

}
getUserTypeList(){
  this.userTypeList = [
    { 'id': 'BankStaff',  'title': 'Bank Staff' },
    { 'id': 'DoerStaff',  'title': 'Doer Staff' }
  ]
}
```

After selecting a user type when I refresh the page is not setting the default value It's always grabbing the value I selected before.

I tried to reset the form in `ngOnInit` like so:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.viFG.reset(this.viFG.value);
}
```

But unfortunately, this didn't work. In addition, I am adding a screenshot:
[image]

After the refresh, I want to set my default drop-down value to "**Select user Type**" which is the placeholder of `p-dropdown`.

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue on Stackblitz?

Answer (score 0):

You can use patchvalue method like:

```
this.viFG.patchValue({
  userType:null
})
```

Comment: where to use this one?

Comment: try to put it under ngOnInit() and comment reset method.

Comment: where you initialized the form?

Comment: I didn't understand your question please ask with clarification.